# How to obtain a component's attribute value from inside componentDidMount()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm rendering some React components in the following way:

```
renderElements(elements) {

    return elements.map(
        (element) => (<Element key={element._id} element={element} />)
    );
}

render() {
    return(
        <div className="parent">
            {this.renderEntries()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now on componentDidMount() I obtain a list of the rendered elements using jquery:

```
componentDidMount(){
    $('.parent').each(function(){
        var listElements = $(this).children();
        listElements.each(function(){
            console.log("Here I need the _id assigned to the component's key attribute...)
        });
    });
}
```

Inside the listElements iteration I would like to access the *_id* value assigned to the component through *key*. Is it possible without making the *_id* visible to the user? I know I could pass it as a custom attribute and retrieve it using .attr('_id'), but I don't want element._id to be visible to the user. Any insights would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

In case anyone's wondering, *_id* is a database entry identifier, and I'd rather keep it away hidden from users if possible. It probably isn't a security issue to display this *_id*, but if there's a way to avoid it, then I'd rather use it.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't need jquery with react, there is no need. You should `ref` with either a string or a function-callback - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html - also the `key` prop is special, it is not available to children, if you want it, you can provide a second prop of `key2` or something. I didn't post this as solution because I'm not sure if there is a way to access `key`, I just remember when I needed it, I was not able to get it and had to use this second prop.

Comment: @Noitidart You are right. But in this case I'm using some jquery-ui functionality and I'm not seeing any other option.

Comment: Why do you need to get the id from the component? you already have the ids in the array `elements`

Comment: @azium I have them but only before rendering. Then the layout is rendered and users make changes to the elements and might trigger the code inside the componentDidMount(). The code in the question is showing a simplification so that I can explain the problem. In the real code, listElement.children() runs inside a callback from an user interaction.

Comment: Maybe your user interactions shouldn't change the DOM, but instead update your react state so you always have a list of ids in JavaScript and never on the DOM. BTW what is it that you're actually doing with jQuery UI? I'm almost certain you can get rid of it.

Comment: @azium If it was possible to do using react state it would be great. I'm using jquery-ui to make a list of elements sortable, then getting the order and storing it on the database. Here https://jqueryui.com/sortable/. It requires the selection of the parent element of the list and apply $( "#sortable" ).sortable(); which I've assumed can't be done before rendering, right?

Comment: https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc ?